# Use Relax NG to verify an XML node is empty and devoid of white space

Tags: xml, validation, whitespace, relaxng

I'd like to use a Relax NG schema to validate an XML file. As part of the validation, I'd like to make sure that there is no white space in a set of nodes. For example, I'd like for the first two `<emptyCheck>` nodes to validate, but the third and fourth ones to fail in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testRoot>
    <emptyCheck/>
    <emptyCheck></emptyCheck>
    <emptyCheck> </emptyCheck>
    <emptyCheck>x</emptyCheck>
</testRoot>
```

The following Relax NG Schema almost works. The above sample XML fails for the fourth instance of `<emptyCheck>`, but not for the third.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar ns="" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
    <start>
        <element name="testRoot">
            <oneOrMore>
                <element name="emptyCheck">
                    <empty/>
                </element>
            </oneOrMore>
        </element>
    </start>
</grammar>
```

I recognize that in most XML processing the node with just white space won't really matter. I'd still like to solve this so I can enforce a coding style guide. So, is there a way to setup a Relax NG schema so that a document won't validate if a node has just white space in it when it should be completely empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can seem quirky of RELAX NG to allow elements declared empty to contain whitespace, though the decision has a [rational basis](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/relax-ng/200102/msg00003.html).

Anyway, if your RELAX NG validator supports XSD data types (most do), then you can use those to constrain the allowed element content further, by specifying that the element content must be a zero-length string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
  datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
  <start>
    <element name="testRoot">
      <oneOrMore>
        <element name="emptyCheck">
          <data type="string">
            <param name="maxLength">0</param>
          </data>
        </element>
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>
</grammar>
```

Comment: The validator I'm using is the one that ships with Oxygen XML Editor (v13). This solution works as expected with it. Thanks.